# Redirecting using JS file instead of HTML event handler?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events, onclick

So currently I want to have my javascript in an attached JS file instead of using the 'OnClick' function attached to HTML objects. So far I've got:

```
<html>
    <head>       
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1 id = '5' class = ''>6</h1>
        <button id = '7' class = ''>8</button>
        <script src = 'js/9.js'></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

But unfortunately, I can't quite get the redirect going from clicking the button. It should have this source

```
document.getElementById('7').onclick = function () {
```

and then redirecting to a different page. Any tips on how I can improve this?

Comment: Are you using jQuery? (as the tags suggest)

Comment: If you put that button in a form with an action, it redirects all on it's own

Comment: Took a glance at form and jquery options as well, they were helpful. TY

Answer (score 2):

1. Please use strings as ID. I know you can now use numbers but it is not recommended
2. Use the load event handler
3. You MAY be submitting the page to itself when not giving the button a type so return false or preventDefault
4. what's with the spacing around = in the attributes? Not necessary nor recommended.

Like this

```
<html>
    <head>       
        <script src="js/9.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1 id="five" class="">6</h1>
        <button id="seven" class="">8</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

where js file has

```
window.onload=function() {
  document.getElementById("seven").onclick = function () {
    location.replace("page2.html"); // or just location="page2.html";
    return false;
  }
}
```

---

Using jQuery it would be

```
<html>
    <head>       
        <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="js/9.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1 id="five" class="">6</h1>
        <button id="seven" class="">8</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

where js file has

```
$(function() {
  $("#seven").on("click",function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    location.replace("page2.html"); // or just location="page2.html";
  });
});
```

LASTLY you do not need script at all:

```
<form action="page2.html">
  <button type="submit" id="seven" class="">8</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Ah thanks for the style tip as well. I will continue on with the new information. Thank you!